# Как отделить знак и числа из математического выражения в Python?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Необходимо из математического выражения (например *12+32*) выделить сначала два числа (*12, 32*), а затем и знак (*+*).

Числа только целые и положительные, знаком могут служить "+", "-", "*", "/".

Думал можно в лоб решить задачу, то есть просто пытаться использовать split() для каждого знака, но хочется более аккуратного решения с помощью регулярных выражений.
Попытался сам составить регулярку, но безуспешно (получилось что-то вроде `\d+[-+/*]\d+`).

Буду благодарен, если поможете понять как здесь использовать регулярные выражения и если посоветуете хорошие материалы для дальнейшего изучения данной темы.

Comment: вот тут https://regex101.com/ можете онлайн поупражняться в регулярных выражениях

Comment: @Сергей ваши ссылки слились в одну, поэтому они не работают. В комментариях используется упрощённое форматирование mini-Markdown: [ссылка] (http://example.com). Необходимо будет удалить пробел между ] и (. Получится [так](http://example.com)

Comment: <habr.com/ru/post/115825/>

Comment: <https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/…>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш подход правильный, только добавить 3 пары скобок в регулярное выражение и применить его:

```
import re

pattern = r"(\d+)([-+/*])(\d+)"

s = "12+3"

parts = re.findall(pattern, s)
num1, op, num2 = parts[0]            # num1 == "12", op == "+", num2 == "3"
```

Но — может быть — вас интересует только результат, а не числа и операнд. Тогда примените стандартную функцию `eval()`:

```
result = eval(s)                    # result == 15
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно. Про eval() знаю, но тут именно разделить нужно было)

Comment: @Egor, не стоит. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю исспользовать модуль SymPy, что в будущем даст более широкие возможности

```
import sympy
exp=sympy.sympify('-1+2 - 3*4 /2',evaluate=False)
exp.atoms()
#{2, 3, 4, -1}
```

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю, что за библиотека.